# Populate a UItableView with new sections when button tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a project where I've created a TableView in a ViewController 1.
        In this VC1 I have also created button (let's call it popupButton) that displays a popupView. 
       The popupview contains some data, i.e. meals represented by buttons. When the button is tapped I collect the meal selected from the popupview and send it back to the VC1 via delegation. I managed to make this work and I can display the meals selected on the UITableView. The problem is I want to populate the tableView depending on the client selected (In VC1 I have UIbuttons representing each client) as following :

- Client 1

  - meal A
  - meal B
- Client 2

  - meal C
  - meal X, etc.

If the button Client 1 is selected and the meal A is tapped create the section C1 as header and meal A meal B and so on. Then when I tap on Client 2 and i select other meals add these meals to a new section whose header will be Client 2. Currently I get Client 1 as the title if it's selected. But if i tap on client 2 and select a new meal it will change the header to Client 2 and won't create a new section. In addition my code works i.e. I can add meals to my table even if no client have been selected at all (it's good so far but I would like it to **only** work when a client is selected)

In the following code I show only the parts that help understand what I did so far . Any idea that would be really appreciated since I've been looking for a while now. I'm thinking about using struct but i don't have any clue about how to mix it with my case. All the examples that I saw seemed to be about static cases while i'm looking for something dynamic. Thank to you dear reader for taking the time to read my problem and helping a ''desperate soul''.

```
var meal: String?  // this var is used to collect the name of the meal

var mycustomer:String = "" // this var gets the name of the customer
    @IBAction func clientselected(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.selected {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        sender.selected = false

        print ("the button is unselected")
       }

    else {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        sender.selected = true
        print ("the button is selected")
        let clientname = sender.titleLabel!.text
        mycustomer = clientname!

        }

var myarray = [String]() // Create an empty array of strings that we can fill later on with the meals selected


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return myarray.count  // Gets the number of strings in the array
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Leschoix", forIndexPath:indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
    cell.textLabel?.text = myarray[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)-> String?
{
    return "\(mycustomer)"}

func foodselected(valuesent:String) { // this func gets the name of the meal tapped in the popUpView through delegation
    let meal = valuesent
        print("OrderViewcontroller\(meal)")
    myarray.append(meal) // each meal selected will be added up to the empty myarray
        print ("Here is the food array \(myarray)")
    self.TableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: I guess this tutorial would help you to manage multiple/nested sections: http://sapandiwakar.in/nested-sections-in-uitableview/

Comment: thank you very much @Santosh I'll read it and try to figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to answer you as far as I understood what you need.

So we want to be able to have more than one section. So we need a variable to make it possible to change the number of sections in the tableView.

```
var numberOfSections: Int = 1

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

     return numberOfSections
}
```

That way we can change `numberOfSections` depending on our needs to have 1 or 2 sections in our TableView.

Then we need to have more than one Array to define the `numberOfRowsInSection`. Otherwise we will have the exact same elements per section. If we use your current version. Both sections would have the exact same content.

```
var sectionOneArray = [String]()
var sectionTwoArray = [String]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

if section == 0 {
     return sectionOneArray.count
}

if section == 1 {
     return sectionTwoArray.count
}

     return 0 
}
```

We'll also need two customer Strings to fill the `titleForHeaderInSection`.

```
var myFirstCustomer = ""
var mySecondCustomer = ""

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        if section == 0 {
            return myFirstCustomer
        }

        if section == 1 {
            return mySecondCustomer
        }
}
```

Now we can populate the arrays and tell our App if we want one or two sections depending on the amount of customers like that. We also need to have a possibility to tell if we choose the Menus in the Popup for Customer 1 or Customer 2, but I currently have no idea what your Popup looks like, but the code would be something like that:

```
func foodselected(valuesent:String) { 

     if popUpChoseForCustomerOne {
          let meal = valuesent

          sectionOneArray.append(meal)
     } 

     if popUpChoseForCustomerTwo {
          let meal = valuesent

          sectionTwoArray.append(meal)
          numberOfSections = 2 
     }     

     self.TableView.reloadData()

}
```

I did this code without IDE, so it might not be perfect. But it should definitely give you the idea of how I would handle the issue.

Comment: Hi @David Seek I tried your solution and it worked!! in order to tell when I choose customer 1 or customer 2 each one of the buttons has a tag. So I get the sender tag and I said number of clients = sender.tag  (since the number of clients determine the number of sections). Something that I think you misunderstood is  that there is only one popupbutton to select the meal so when i tap that popupbutton, I have access to the different meals. Finally When I applied the approach it brought a new problem (that I'm glad to have lol since it works). I'll explain in a further comment. THANKS again!

Answer (score 0):

Following @David Seek inspiration,

I created a variable that gets the number of clients since the number of clients will correspond to the number of sections of the table view. this number changes depending on if client 1 is selected (1 section), client 2, (2 sections) or client 3..and so on. Since I assigned to each of the button a tag I get the tag as shown below:

```
var numberofclients:Int = 1
@IBAction func clientselected(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.selected {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        sender.selected = false

        print ("the button is unselected")
       }

    else {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        sender.selected = true
        let clientname = sender.titleLabel!.text
        mycustomer = clientname!
        numberofclients = sender.tag
        print ("the button \(numberofclients) is selected")

        }
```

Then I created 2 empty strings that I fill with the meal selected by each clients:

```
var firstarray = [String]()
var secondarray = [String]()
```

And after implementation in the tableview it looks like this:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {


    return numberofclients

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {

    return firstarray.count  // Gets the number of strings in the array of C1
        }
    if section == 1 {

        return secondarray.count  // Gets the number of strings in the array of C2
    }


    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Leschoix", forIndexPath:indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
    if indexPath.section == 0 { // If you are in section 1, i.e, if client 1 is selected fill the first array with the meal selected
    cell.textLabel?.text = firstarray[indexPath.row]
        }
    if indexPath.section == 1 // If you are in section 2, i.e. if client 2 is selected, fill the second array with the meal selected by the client
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = secondarray[indexPath.row]
    }


    return cell

}
```

In order to fill the cells I used David's idea in a switch

```
func poutinechoisie(valuesent:String) {
    let meal = valuesent
        print("OrderViewcontroller\(mealselected)")

    switch numberofclients {
    case 1:
    firstarray.append(meal)
        print ("here is the first array \(firstarray)")

    case 2:
        secondarray.append(meal)
        print ("here is the second \(c2array)")
       }
```

I haven't yet created the cells for the header section. I ran the program first to see what I get and it worked!:

when I select Client 1 it means I have 1 section so I click the popupButton and I can add the foods I want. Then when I select Client 2 (the tag is now 2) I have 2 sections so I can also add the foods I want and I get this:

- Client 1
- meal A
- meal B
- Client 2
- meal C
- meal D

But when I decide to add a new meal to Client 1 (let's say a meal E) it deletes everything I had added for client 2 and it shows this :

- Client 1
- meal A
- meal B
- meal E

I think it has something to do with the fact that when i reselect client 1 the number of clients changes from 2 to 1 and it deletes everything added before. So I'll now think about some ways to fix this new interesting issue.

I've also noted that if I decide to tap on button 2 first which means take the client 2 order (a meal C) before client 1 it creates 2 sections with the 1st one being blank (see below).

- Client 1
- Blank
- Client 2
- meal C

So far it doesn't bother me but I guess there is a way to have only one section and display something like :

- Client 2
- meal C